# How to use a ruby hash as a options for javascript function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I have a hash in ruby which holds options which I want to input for a javascript function

my hash is (as it prints in irb)

```
@options = [{:source=>"2", :tries=>"3"}]
```

my javascript function accepts options like

```
myFunc({source: num, tries: num})
```

So if in a js.erb file I do

```
myFunc(<%=j @options %>)
```

It would result in

```
{:source=&gt;\&quot;2\&quot;, :tries=&gt;\&quot;3\&quot;}
```

doing `j @edges.to_json` results in

```
 \&quot;{:source=&gt;\\\&quot;2\\\&quot;, :target=&gt;\\\&quot;3\\\&quot;} }\&quot;
```

doing `j @edges.to_json.html_safe` results in

```
\"{:source=>\\\"2\\\", :target=>\\\"3\\\"}\"
```

Is there way to make it output a more javascript friendly hash?

Comment: try @options[0].to_json

Comment: The content is being scaped, try `@options.to_json.html_safe`

Answer (score 4):

dont use `j`. try

```
myFunc(<%= @options.to_json %>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `gsub` to remove those unwanted chars:

```
@options[0].to_json.gsub(/\"/,'')
# => "{source:2,tries:3}"
```